# React Native useState change from a function is not re-rendering the components

Tags: react-native, use-state

I've tried a lot of answers given to similar questions but nothing is fixing my problem as I'm changing the state in a function which I'm calling on the press of a button in a third-part library I'm using.

I'm using [react-native-horizontal-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@logisticinfotech/react-native-horizontal-date-picker) and upon select a date I'm calling a function in which I'm changing the state.

```
<HorizontalDatePicker
    pickerType={'date'}
    dayFormat={'Do'}
    monthFormat={'MMM'}
    yearFormat={'YYYY'}
    returnDateFormat={'DD-MM-YYYY'}
    onDateSelected={(date) => {
        if (date) {
            getTimeData()
        }
    }}
/>
```

Then in my `getTimeData` function I'm updating the `const [timeSlots, setTimeSlots] = useState([]);` state:

```
function getTimeData() {
...
            if (timeAvailable) {
                setTimeSlots(finalTimeSlots)
            } else if (!timeAvailable) {
                setTimeSlots([])
            }
...
}
```

based on the `timeSlots` array I'm updating the UI, now I have to tap twice on the date to be able to see the results getting rendered.

I'm passing `timeSlots` to another custom component that I made:

```
<TimePicker timeSlotsArray={timeSlots} />
```

How do I achieve this in this scenario?

Comment: Where are you using the timeSlots array?

Comment: @FrankelyDiaz I'm passing it to another component `<TimePicker timeSlotsArray={timeSlots} />`

Comment: You need to create a useEffect hook inside of this function you pass a timeslots array into that so whenever you select the component will update and render. something like this.

useEffect(()=>{ },[timeslot]);

Comment: @sauravsingh your suggestion worked. Thank you so much :)